# Assign class to link element where href is equal to a specific value using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I assign  `class="active"` to a link element when another link is clicked?

i.e I have:

```
<div id="wrap">
   <a href="one.php"></a>
   <a href="two.php"></a>
   <a href="three.php"></a>
</div>

<a href="one.php"></a>
<a href="two.php"></a>
<a href="three.php"></a>
```

But when the the link for one.php is clicked below, I want the link in the div wrap above to have the active class, as so:

```
<div id="wrap">
   <a href="one.php" class="active"></a>
   <a href="two.php"></a>
   <a href="three.php"></a>
</div>

<a href="one.php"></a>
<a href="two.php"></a>
<a href="three.php"></a>
```

Basically I was thinking something like:

```
var foo = $(this).attr("href");
if ($(this).attr("href") == "hello.php")
   $("#wrap").//something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `click` event listener to every anchor element that adds the `active` class to every anchor, then removes the `active` class on the anchor element clicked.

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  $('a').addClass('active');
  $(this).removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">link 1</a>

<a href="#">link 2</a>
```

Comment: I did a poor job of explaining my goal, I updated my original question. Your idea makes perfect sense, I see what you did. But if I were to have 5 links, wouldn't the other 4, excluding the one clicked, have a yellow background? How could I select a single one of the links (inside the div, I updated the question) in order to append a "class='active'" to it if it has no unique IDs, just a uniqure href?